# Strings - How to stop prompting after user enters a certain word

Tags: java

I have to create a program that constantly prompts the user for a String, but when they enter the word "stop" I have to stop the prompting. How would I go about doing that (the stop part)? I have most of my code done, except for the part where if they enter "stop" it stops the prompting. I feel like it's fairly simple and I'm just overthinking it. Would I use a while loop? I'm struggling to find any help online. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Strings {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter anything: ");
    String name;
    name = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + name);
```

There is more to my code, but the rest of it is just details that I had to add in as requested by my professor (like the length of the word entered, etc.) and I already figured all that out. I'm just really struggling with the "stop" part.

Comment: Tell us what have you accomplished so far ?

Comment: @Dren yeah for sure. I just added some of my code, at least what I think is relevant with what I'm asking. The only thing I have with the "stop" part is a while loop that I started, but ultimately ended up deleting it because I didn't think it was correct

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have written some code by yourself, but anyway, this problem that you are facing can be solved with a loop.

First, declare a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) variable so it can be like our flag so that we know when our program will stop.

```
private static final String SENTINEL = "END";
```

Then ask the user to enter his name.

```
System.out.println("Enter your name");
   String name = sc.nextLine();
```

In the end, we keep the loop true so it can repeat itself until it equals the Sentinel so then it will stop

```
while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)){
              //do something
    }
```

Full code

```
 private static final String SENTINEL = "END";

   System.out.println("Enter your name");
   String name = sc.nextLine();

   while(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)){
          //do something
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help. I for some reason had while (true) and then put an if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) in there as well. Not sure what I was thinking lol. Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  This simply takes in the words and continues to store them in a list until you enter STOP.  Then it prints the list.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
String word = "";
String prompt = "Please enter a word: ";
System.out.print(prompt);
while (!(word = scanner.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
    words.add(word);    
    System.out.print(prompt);   
}

words.forEach(System.out::println);
```

You also need to keep prompting inside the loop.